# помогите конвертировать код c в ардуино

Tags: c++, arduino, конвертация

Есть программа на c, которая считает к меры днк, нашел на просторах интернета, понадобилась для урока биологии. биологичка у нас не понимает в пк, поэтому лучший вариант конвертация.
оно должно выводить данные в монитор порта

```
#include
#include

using namespace std;

char convert(char c)
{
if (c == 'A') return 'C';
if (c == 'C') return 'G';
if (c == 'G') return 'T';
if (c == 'T') return 'A';
return ' ';
}

int main()
{
cout << "Start" << endl;

string opt = "ACGT";
string s = "";
string s_last = "";
int len_str = 13;
bool change_next;

for (int i=0; i<len_str; i++)
{
s += opt[0];
}

for (int i=0; i<len_str; i++)
{
s_last += opt.back();
}

int pos = 0;
int counter = 1;
while (s != s_last)
{
counter ++;
// Следующая строка выводит результаты // cout << s << endl; change_next = true; for (int i=0; i<len_str; i++) { if (change_next) { if (s[i] == opt.back()) { s[i] = convert(s[i]); change_next = true; } else { s[i] = convert(s[i]); break; } } } } // Следующая строка выводит результаты // cout << s << endl; cout << "Number of generated k-mers: " << counter << endl; cout << "Finish!" << endl; return 0; }
```

Comment: О каком си идёт речь? Здесь только вижу с++

Comment: именно, это он, и это надо как то переделать в ардуиновский код